# Same value is setting to another field on click

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.8

i am using autocomplete in which  country field and then state and city so, when i click on state field the value of country field getting the same value of state even before going on state we set the value of country.

laravel code

```
if($request->get('name'))
 {
    $name = $request->get('name');

    $data = country::select("country_name")
            ->where("country_name","LIKE","%{$request->input('name')}%")
            ->get();

            $output = '<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="cnt" style="display:block; position:absolute">';
            foreach($data as $row)
            {
             $output .= '
             <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">'.$row->country_name.'</span></li>
             ';
            }
            $output .= '</ul>';
            echo $output;

}
```

the state code is same as country code the difference is that it's fetching the data from states table

html & jquery code

```
<div class="col-sm-4 m-clear">
    <label>Country</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control " id="country" name="country">
    <div class="countryList" style="z-index:999;">
    <div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 m-clear">
    <label>State</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" name="state">
    <div class="stateList" style="z-index:999;">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery code

```
                // country fetching
                $("#country").keyup(function(){

                var name=$(this).val();

                    if(name !=''){
            ds="name="+name;
            $.ajax({
            headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url:'{{route('get-country.fetchC')}}',
            type:'POST',
            data:ds,
            success:function(data){
                //console.log(data);
             $('.countryList').fadeIn();  
             $('.countryList').html(data);
              }, 
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
                    }
                });

            }

            $(document).on('click','li',function(){  
                        $('#country').val($(this).text());  
                        $('.countryList').fadeOut();  
                        }); 

            });

                    // state fetching
                    $("#state").keyup(function(){

                        var state=$(this).val();

                            if(state !=''){
                        st="state="+state;
                        $.ajax({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        },
                        url:'{{route('get-state.fetchS')}}',
                        type:'POST',
                        data:st,
                        success:function(data){
                        //console.log(data);
                        $('.stateList').fadeIn();  
                        $('.stateList').html(data);
                        }, 
                        error: function (data) {
                        console.log('Error:', data);
                            }
                        });

                        }

                        $(document).on('click','li',function(){  
                        $('#state').val($(this).text());  
                        $('.stateList').fadeOut();  
                        });  

                        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is with your `$(document).on('click','li',function() ...`

You have declared the following event listeners:

```
$(document).on('click','li',function(){  
  $('#country').val($(this).text())
})
$(document).on('click','li',function(){  
  $('#state').val($(this).text())
})
```

Suppose I click `<li>America</li>`... both of those events will trigger and both will set to the same value.

What you need to do is distinguish both handlers with unique lists.

Set your list containing countries to `<ul id="country">` and your states to `<ul id="states">`

Then bind your event listeners respectively:

```
$(document).on('click','#country > li',function(){
  $('#country').val($(this).text())
})
$(document).on('click','#states > li',function(){
  $('#country').val($(this).text())
})
```

Comment: **thanks bro** yes i did the same thing before posting question but i am doing in (here).on('click','no here',function())